# ReactJS - importing component breaks webpack

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, import

My ReactJS app default version works fine. While I am upgrading my app to create new version and try to import new component, it messes up all the styles. New component doesn't have any style elements. I feel that when I am importing new component then webpack doesn't consider existing css files. When I import missing css files manually in imported component then it works well.

**WEBPACK:** :

```html
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  },
  watch: true,
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module:{
    loaders: [
      {
        test:/\.js$/,
        exclude:/node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets:['react','es2015', 'stage-1']
        }
      },
      {
         test:/\.(s*)css$/,
         use:['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
         include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/css')
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        loaders: [
          'file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
          'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
      }
    ],

  }
}
```

**React Component:**

`

```
import React from 'react'
import Header from './Header-backupWithSignup';
import Contact from './Contact';
import SiteMap from './SiteMap';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import Upgrades from './Upgrades';
import Carefree from './Carefree';
import Trails from './Trails';
import AreaMap from './AreaMap';
import Siteplan from './Siteplan';
import Features from './Features';
import HomeDetails from './HomeDetails';
import Homes from './Homes';
import '../css/Stickey.css'
import $ from 'jquery'
import BottomStickyNav from './BottomStickyNav';
import CMS from './CMS/CMS';
import ProjectTemplateService from './../services/projectTemplateServices';
import AboutService from './../services/aboutService';
import Login from './Authentication/login';
import update from 'immutability-helper';
import '../css/master.css';
```

`

If I remove import master.css statement then everything breaks. master.css file does have all other css files imported into it.

We want to ensure webpack is used for live reload / syncing updated css, instead of hard coding css links inline in our pages

Please help.

npm version : 6.x
node version : 10.x
Attaching webpack file here.

Comment: rule for css/scss is wrong. That is taking in consideration css and applying sass-loader for css files, which might mess everything. Split that rule for scss and other just for css.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I modified webpack by adding 2 different sections for css and scss like below & still its not working :( :
`

{
        test:/\.css$/,
        use:['style-loader','css-loader'],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/css')
      },
      {
         test:/\.scss$/,
         use:['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
         include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/css')
      },


`